# How to get the url of an Image with id

Tags: images, pods-framework

If I have the id of an image media file, how can I get the url, to download it via rest api?
I'm using the Pods Plugin to create my own objects. thes have images included i want to download via rest api.

I tried

```
wp_get_attachment_image_src( $imgid, $default );
```

or

```
wp_get_original_image_path($imgid);
```

all came back empty
I got the id with

```
$imgid = $designpod->fields( 'app_logo' )→id;
```

i also tried

```
$imgid = $designpod->fields( 'app_logo' )->id;
$design["app_logo"] = $designpod->pods_image_url($imgid, null );
```

also not working /returns empty.

that also seems to return the wrong id. it returns 75, but if i look it up in media, it has 76 as id.
Sorry, I have no clue about PHP - i'm a C# programmer.
Maybe anyone can help me with this.

Thanks!